# What is the size of notification payload in ios 11?

Tags: ios, push-notification

Can any one tell me the size of payload in ios 11. For ios 8 i know it is 2KB But for ios 11 i dont know is it changed or it remains same as for ios 8?
please tell me.
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html):

> The maximum size of the payload depends on the notification you are
>   sending:
>
> - For regular remote notifications, the maximum size is 4KB (4096 bytes)
> - For Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP) notifications, the maximum size is 5KB (5120 bytes)
>
> Note: If you are using the legacy APNs binary interface to send
>   notifications instead of an HTTP/2 request, the maximum payload size
>   is 2KB (2048 bytes)

Answer (score 0):

Yes the maximum size of payload is 4KB.

When using the HTTP/2 based APNS provider API, the maximum size for your JSON dictionary is 4KB. For legacy APIs, the payload size is smaller.

For more [check this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/PayloadKeyReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH17-SW1)